# How to set /dev/root filesystem size to the partition size

Tags: yocto

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       4.3G  1.9G  2.2G  47% /
devtmpfs        980M     0  980M   0% /dev
tmpfs           981M     0  981M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           981M   33M  948M   4% /run
tmpfs           981M     0  981M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           981M     0  981M   0% /tmp
tmpfs           981M   16K  981M   1% /var/volatile
```

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 7.3 GiB, 7818182656 bytes, 15269888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier:

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1 16384    24575     8192    4M unknown
/dev/mmcblk1p2 24576    32767     8192    4M unknown
/dev/mmcblk1p3 32768    69859    37092 18.1M unknown
/dev/mmcblk1p4 81920 15269854 15187935  7.2G unknown
```

As far as I know, the /dev/root filesystem size is the size of the content that is being copied to the /dev/root.

My goal is to have /dev/root size the same as /dev/mmcblk1p4 which is 7.2G.
How can I instruct Yocto give the /dev/root filesystem the size of the partition it is mounted to?

Comment: What's your filesystem on /dev/root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions to your issue.

The first one is by telling Yocto to generate an image with a sepcific `IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE` value. As stated in the [Yocto Mega-Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE). The size is specified in KBytes. Modify your `machine.conf` or `local.conf` to add this parameter.

In your case, the value seems to be:

```
15269854 - 81920 = 15187934 sectors
sectors are 512 Bytes on your system (see verification below)
15187935 * 512 = 7776222208 Bytes
7776222208 / 1024 = 7593967 KBytes

To verify the sector size of 512B: 
7593967 / (1024 * 1024) = 7.242 GB
With 512 Bytes blocksize, the partition size is 7.2GB, as stated by fdisk
```

I think it is a good idea to reduce it a little bit, a value like 7230000 Kilobytes (~7.23 GB) can be a good candidate.

The other method is to use resize2fs program if your partition type is ext2/3/4. This program can be executed on mounted or unmounted devices. If you are using a SDcard, the simplest method will be to insert it into your computer, to unmount it, and run `resize2fs /dev/<mysdcarddevice>`. You can also execute it directly from your embedded board. In this case you will need to add the package `e2fsprogs-resize2fs` on the board with `IMAGE_INSTALL += "e2fsprogs-resize2fs"`, then run `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk1p4`.

Answer (score 2):

As PierreOlivier proposed I used `resize2fs` program.
Because I am using Yocto to build the custom image I use  `pkg_postinst_ontarget` which runs only once at the first boot on the target machine.
In one of my recipe I put

```
pkg_postinst_ontarget_${PN}() {
    #!/bin/bash
    resize2fs /dev/mmcblk1p4
}
```

This resizes the selected partition on the first boot.
Thank you PierreOlivier